# Adobe Flex and data push

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, client-server, push

I found one similar question here, but answer wasn't that helpful, so I'm hoping to get more lucky :)

I'm making a "Risk"-alike game in flex as a university project with my friend. We made all the logic related to creating a new game and allowing multiple users to join in. However, right now, we're updating each client with "pings" that get game state from server.

Obviously, this isn't the best way to do this, and I'd like to have some kind kind of server data push implementation.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Cheers

Comment: Not sure it's possible with php. Can you move to Java/BlazeDS?

Comment: not at this moment, unfortunately :(... thx for answering, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many flex apis use event notification (eg NetStream ) to keep the client up to date with what's happening on the server. Here's an example that uses .net: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_RTMP_Data_Push_from__NET_to_Flex-16983.html

Comment: thx for your answer! looks like this could be tweaked to be used with this project. fingers crossed! :)